# Using the index of items in a list to compare the order they come in the list

Tags: python, indexing

I'm trying to compare the order of items in a list through assigning them to names. I've used 'if' statements to attempt this but it doesn't seem to be working. I think I might need to find the index of the item in the list and then figure out which is the greater of the two.

Here is my code:

> import re, sys
>
> f = open('findallEX.txt', 'r')
>
> for line in f.readlines():
>
> ```
>   match = re.findall('[A-Z]+', line)
>
>   ii=0
>
>   if index in match: 'VERB'
>
>   verbindex = ii
>
>   ii = ii + 1
>
>   ii=0
>
>   if index in match: 'OBJ'
>
>   objindex = ii
>
>   ii = ii + 1
> ```

I've used the name 'index' just to demonstrate what I think it's need to be. Is there anyway to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I can't really understand the question. Would a dictionary be helpful?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the goal of `if index in match: 'OBJ'` is, but that statement does literally nothing.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself very well. If i had a list such as ['VERB', 'SUBJ', 'OBJ'], I want to find the position of VERB in the list, then OBJ, and compare the order using the numerical value of their position in the list.

Comment: Maybe enumerate() help you in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
>>> data = ['VERB', 'SUBJ', 'OBJ']
>>> for n, i in enumerate(data):
...     print n, i
... 
0 VERB
1 SUBJ
2 OBJ
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the index of an item in the list:

```
>>> ['VERB', 'SUBJ', 'OBJ'].index('SUBJ')
1
```